# Decimal ToString including insignificant characters

Tags: c#

If you execute the following line of Code:

```
((15m)*(1.0000m)).ToString()
```

You get the result of "15.0000"

I have a long lived object which gets serialized to a binary format, when we print the value out after re-hydrating it, we end up with the insignificant 0's.

It looks like decimals retain the information about the greatest percision used on them. Even if the precision is insignificant. How can I display only the significant digits?

Comment: Try `ToString(".00######")`

Comment: duh thanks you should add an answer and I will accept iot

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
((15m)*(1.0000m).ToString(".00######");
```

This results in 15.00

To get 15 use a format string of ".#####" which allows a precision of 5 to still be listed.

Comment: Had to modify slightly and since I only need a max precision of 5 anyways this works for me! Thanks

Comment: @JoshBerke - That's fine. I just wanted to give you a general idea of what you needed to do.

Comment: Yep well this really close would still love to see the significant zeros dropped so if my precision ever changed I wouldn't have to adjust the format string. Thanks for the help getting me over that mental roadblock